# PHP cURL adds random character in downloaded xml file

Tags: php, xml, curl, random, character-encoding

I'm trying to access a SOAP API with PHP and for this I need to download a copy of a WSDL description file on my computer using PHP cURL.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
$credit = ('some_username'.':'.'some_password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://somevalidaddress/file.asmx?WSDL');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $credit);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);


$path = 'C:\Wamp\www\mmx\test2.xml';

file_put_contents($path, $data);

?>
```

The file test2.xml contains, ***every time*** at line 345 (on a total number of 684 lines) a random character (e.g. ø, @, or VT, etc.). Also, the ***last character*** of the file is ***stripped***.

I googled the thing and I read about Off-by-one errors and buffer overflow but still, I have no solution to my problem.

Any idea ? Thanks!

Comment: If you download file with just say, a browser, does the problem persist? If it does, it's a problem with the remote service.

Comment: I have no problem when downloading the file with a browser and then looking at it with Notepad++. The file is fine this way.

Comment: Also please note that when using the test service of this API, the cURL download works just fine. Maybe because the WSDL test service description is shorter (68 lines) ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using this :

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
));
$data = file_get_contents('https://somevalidaddress/file.asmx?WSDL', false, $context);
```

Comment: And what if allow_url_fopen=off?

Comment: @Loïc Just tried it, now it adds a random character at the ***end*** of the file (e.g. ß). The file still can't be parsed by PHP Soap class.

Comment: then strip the last character before feeding it to php SOAP class?

Comment: Ha ! You're right, that should work ! But I wish I could keep allow_url_fopen=off as @baldrs said. Any idea on a cURL solution ?

Comment: Try adding more headers from browser and possibly some cookies